# user.authenticate(params[:password]) wrong number of arguments 0 for 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my sessions controller for logging in a user I do:

```
     user = User.find_by_email(params[:email].downcase)
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
      else
        redirect_to :back, alert: "Email or password is invalid"
      end
```

And I am getting an error on the `authenticate` method call:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

My user model does have `has_secure_password`

Whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to use devise and it was calling the devise `authenticate` method instead of `bcrypts`,
removing devise fixed the issue.

Comment: You should flag your own answer as correct answer, so it doesn't show as unsolved

Comment: @stef I cant for another day.